# Is there a better way to reference sub-features so that this test finishes?

Tags: karate

When running the following scenario, the tests finish running but execution hangs immediately after and the gradle test command never finishes. The cucumber report isn't built, so it hangs before that point.

It seems to be caused by having 2 call read() to different scenarios, that both call a third scenario. That third scenario references the parent context to inspect the current request.
When that parent request is stored in a variable the tests hang. When that variable is cleared before leaving that third scenario, the test finishes as normal. So something about having a reference to that context hangs the tests at the end.

Is there a reason this doesn't complete? Am I missing some important code that lets the tests finish?

I've added * def currentRequest = {}  at the end of the special-request scenario and that allows the tests to complete, but that seems like a hack.

This is the top-level test scenario:

```
  Scenario: Updates user id
      * def user = call read('utils.feature@endpoint=create-user')
      * set user.clientAccountId = user.accountNumber + '-test-client-account-id'
      * call read('utils.feature@endpoint=update-user') user
      * print 'the test is done!'
```

The test scenario calls 2 different scenarios in the same utls.feature file

utils.feature:

```
  @ignore
  Feature: /users

  Background:
      * url baseUrl

  @endpoint=create-user
  Scenario: create a standard user for a test
    Given path '/create'
    * def restMethod = 'post'
    * call read('special-request.feature')
    When method restMethod
    Then status 201


  @endpoint=update-user
  Scenario: set a user's client account ID
    Given path '/update'
    * def restMethod = 'put'
    * call read('special-request.feature')
    When method restMethod
    Then status 201
    And match response == {"status":"Success", "message":"Update complete"}
```

Both of the util scenarios call the special-request feature with different parameters/requests.

special-request.feature:

```
  @ignore
  Feature: Builds a special

  Scenario: special-request
      # The next line causes the test to sit for a long time 
      * def currentRequest = karate.context.parentContext.getRequest() 
      # Without the below clear of currentRequest, the test never finishes
      # We are de-referencing the parent context's request allows test to finish
      * def currentRequest = {}
```

without currentRequest = {} these are the last lines of output I get before the tests seem to stop.

```
12:21:38.816 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 8.48
1 < 201
1 < Content-Type: application/json
{
  "status": "Success",
  "message": "Update complete"
}


12:21:38.817 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $
12:21:38.817 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $
12:21:38.817 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $
12:21:38.817 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $
12:21:38.818 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] the test is done!
12:21:38.818 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $
<==========---> 81% EXECUTING [39s]
```

With currentRequest = {}, the test completes and the cucumber report generates successfully which is what I would expect to happen even without that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two comments:

```
* karate.context.parentContext.getRequest()
```

Wow, these are internal API-s not intended for users to use, I would strongly advise passing values around as variables instead. So all bets are off if you have trouble with that.

It does sound like you have a null-pointer in the above (no surprises here).

There is a bug in 0.9.4 that causes test failures in some edge cases such as the things you are doing, pre-test life-cycle or failures in `karate-config.js` to hang the parallel runner. You should see something in the logs that indicates a failure, if not - do try help us replicate this problem.

This should be fixed in the `develop` branch, so you could help if you can build from source and test locally. Instructions are here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

And if you still see a problem, *please* do this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem with the develop branch, so I will submit an issue in the next day or so.(Whenever I get time to make a skeleton project with it)  As a heads up, I also got file not found issues when upgrading to the develop branch that will probably show up in the example project:  src.test.java.org.infoarmor.subscriptionbilling.subscriber.api.karate.feature.subscriber:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /src/test/java/org/infoarmor/subscriptionbilling/subscriber/api/karate/feature/utils.feature (No such file or directory)